# rails 4 custom path Sort table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, rails-routing, link-to

I followed http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns to make a sortable table on my records index.erb

So everything works good for that, but now I've gone back to my homepage and put this code in the index.erb for my home object:

```
<%= link_to "Records Index", records_path %>
```

And I get a sql error:

[image]

So anyway, I went back to records page that was working and saw that my application_helper.rb was doing this to the URL

> http://localhost:3000/records**?direction=asc&sort=firstname**

So now a simple records_path call doesn't work. What would work instead? I tried

```
records_path & "?direction=asc&sort=firstname"
```

but that didn't help either. can you help me? thanks!

Comment: Well, the error from what it shows in your screenshot seems to have to do with your columns in the table, rather than the controller. As if your controller is trying to reference a column which doesn't actually exist. You have double checked the schema.rb file to make sure that column exists, and have run all of your pending migrations right?

Answer (score 0):

I thought perhaps I should fix the Def for index in the records controller so I was trying stuff like this

```
class RecordsController < ApplicationController
...
  def index
    if sort_column.blank? #sort_direction.nil? || sort_column.nil?
      @records = Record.all
    else
      @records = Record.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
    end
  end
```

but that didn't work. so I tried this on the home page:

```
<%= link_to "Records Index", '\records?direction=asc&sort=firstname' %>
```

I'm certain there's a much better way to do this using the routes or correcting something in application helper or records controller but this'll work for me.